# RUNOFF PSET3 - bool is_tie(int min) function gives an error in Check50 unable to remove

Tags: c, function, boolean, cs50

I have tried a number of ways to execute the code in bool is_tie function; however, I always seem to receive the same error in check50.

That said, I have run the program with the below function without any issues using the max candidates, 10 voters and with 7 eliminated candidates or 2, the program prints out the 2 tied candidates without issue.

I have run the code through debug50 and it seems to work correctly by displaying the names of the tied candidates after eliminating two others; however, in the check50 tool the above error continues to come up.

I have also used the printf function to display all of the values within the function and all of them seem to be correct as well.

I have also used else {istie = false;} in the below is_tie function I am having an issue with; however, I receive the same error below as I get with the code also below the error.

**:( is_tie detects tie after some candidates have been eliminated - is_tie did not return true **

```
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    int ties = 0;
    bool istie = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min && candidates[i].eliminated == false)
        {
            ties++;
            int elim_cands = candidate_count - candidates_out;

            if (ties == candidate_count || ties == elim_cands)
            {
                istie = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                istie = false;
            }

        }

    }
    return istie;
}
```

Similarily, I have been able to remove the error with this code immediately below; however, I only receive these two errors instead.

**:( is_tie returns false when election is not tied

is_tie did not return false

:( is_tie returns false when only some of the candidates are tied

is_tie did not return false**

```
 bool is_tie(int min)
{
    int ties = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min && candidates[i].eliminated == false)
        {
            ties++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know what I can try. I have been working on this same error for the entire day and although the program works for me, I cannot submit it with the error.  Your ideas would be appreciated.

All of the other functions are working correctly and the main code from the problem set is the same as originally provided. I did; however, add a global variable called candidates_out to keep track of the number of eliminated candidates.

**HERE IS THE MAIN PROGRAM**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9


// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];
// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;
int candidates_out = 0;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {

        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**SPOLER ALERT - BELOW IS THE CODE FOR FUNCTIONS RELATED TO PROGRAM:

bool vote(int voter,int rank, string name) (void)tabulate(void) bool print_winner(void) bool is_tie(int min) int find_min(void) eliminate(int min)

```
   bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
   {
    for (int number = 0; number < candidate_count; number++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[number].name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = number;
            return true;
        }


    }
    return false;
}

    // Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
    void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)  //loop to record each voters rank 1
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
        {
            int number = preferences[i][j];

            if (candidates[number].eliminated == false) //if candidate is not eliminated, add 1 to candidates votes
            {
                candidates[number].votes += 1;
                j = 0;
            }
            else                                        //if candidate is eliminated, go to the same voters next preference
            {
                i--;
                j++;
            }
        }

    }
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    float majority = (float)voter_count / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > majority)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int min = candidates[0].votes;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (min > candidates[i].votes && candidates[i].eliminated == false)
        {
            min = candidates[i].votes;
            int Position = i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}


// Eliminate the candidate (or candidiates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
            candidates_out++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem:

> add a global variable called candidates_out to keep track of the number of eliminated candidates.

From [the spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/runoff/):

> you should not modify anything else in `plurality.c`

check50 uses it's own black magic to run tests and verify results. IMO one of the important skills learned in this class is following the spec *to the letter*. In a business setting, not doing so could translate to real money.

Comment: Lesson learned. Apparently the check50 tests the functions independently so the if statement was never returning true.  Hours wasted by not following the spec _to the letter_ .  In the end I was able to solve the code by simply checking if non eliminated candidates (==min / tied) or (!=min / not tied) and returning them with a value of true or false.