# error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths

Tags: c, algorithm

```
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    bool tied;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
         if (candidates[i].votes == min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
             {
                tied = true;
             }
         else
              {
                tied = false;
              }
    return false;
    }
}   






~/pset3/runoff/ $ make runoff
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    runoff.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o runoff
runoff.c:208:1: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}    
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: runoff] Error 1
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code, I tried to take out the bracket but it showed even more errors and now I have no clue why it is showing this.

Comment: You have a `return` statement **inside** the `for` loop and nothing after the loop. Is that what you meant to write?

Comment: As your code stands, if `candidate_count` is greater than 0 the loop will iterate once and then unconditionally return `false`, which I don't think is what you want.  And if `candidate_count` is 0 or negative it will return without a value at all (hence the error).

Comment: The compiler error as well as the two comments above explain the syntactic error, but the function is also meaningless in several ways which cannot be solved from the question. I assume this is homework. In this question they have more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728647/runoff-pset3-bool-is-tieint-min-function-gives-an-error-in-check50-unable-to?rq=1.

Comment: Please select an indenting style and stick to it. Your error will be instantly visible.